# TableView not showing in android titanium appcelerator

Tags: android, ios, titanium, tableview, appcelerator

The TableView is showing in iOS simulator...but it doesn't show in android physical device...
They are running the same code and without error occur.

```
var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
                width : Titanium.UI.FILL,
                height : "20%",
                left : 0,
                backgroundColor : "orange",
                separatorColor : "transparent",
                fav_id:id,
            });

        var lblTitle = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            top : "5%",
            left : "0%",
            height : Titanium.UI.SIZE,
            width : "90%",
            text : title,
            textAlign : Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
            color : "black",
            //backgroundColor : 'blue',
            maxLines: 2,
            touchEnabled : false
        });

        var lblDate = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            top : "50%",
            left : "0%",
            height : Titanium.UI.SIZE,
            width : "90%",
            text : date,
            textAlign : Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
            color : "black",
            //backgroundColor : 'blue',
            //maxLines:1,
            touchEnabled : false
        });

        var lblCategory = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            top : "50%",
            left : "60%",
            height : Titanium.UI.SIZE,
            width : "90%",
            text : category,
            textAlign : Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
            color : "black",
            touchEnabled : false
            //backgroundColor : 'white',
            //maxLines:1,
        });

        row.add(lblTitle);
        row.add(lblDate);
        row.add(lblCategory);
        dataTable.push(row);
$.tblFavourite.data = dataTable;
```

what happened to the android os? does design affected to the output of the tableview?

Comment: I think the problem is due to `height : "20%",`.

Comment: @Swanand the height is the row height, it's not the height for the whole tableview...

Comment: @jefferyleo Try to set row.height = "50dp"

Comment: I think percentage is not working in case of tableView row.

Comment: @Surajkochale omg...you helped me on this! thank you, how do I mark you as a correct answer?

Comment: @jefferyleo Now you can mark this as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think percentage is not working in case of tableViewRow.
Try to set `row.height = "50dp"`
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As Suraj already pointed out it is not possible to use percentages as the row height in Android. But there is a workaround I found in [the Appcelerator forums](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/131723/setting-height-with-percentage-on-tableviewrow-does-not-work-for-android):

You should calculate your percentage by yourself. Use `Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth` and `Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight` for your calculation.

Example for 10% height:

```
height : Math.floor(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight / 10)
```

Comment: I can did it by this way as well.